# IONIC 3 - Unable to build release android apk

Tags: android, cordova, build, ionic3, release

Ionic info

[image]

Cordova requirements

[image]

ionic cordova build android --release

[image]

Comment: Use android studio to install sdk components and create a emulator in it to test and avoid these issues

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have not accepted the license agreement of the SDK component Android SDK Platform 26.

You can do so by navigating to your android sdkmanager on your command prompt and running

> sdkmanager --licenses

there after they will tell you that you have license agreements that you have yet to accept and you just need to accept it all.

For reference my android sdkmanager is located in

> C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\bin